# How to use a private azure devops repository with yeoman generators

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have a private azure devops repository with yeoman templates.
How can I use this private repo with yeoman without exposing it out of company?

Thank you in advance for your help.

BR

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same question.